# Need help pairing data

Tags: r

I'm looking for what I'm sure is a quick answer. I'm working with a data set that looks like this:

```
    Week      Game.ID           VTm VPts HTm HPts Differential HomeWin 
    1  NFL_20050908_OAK@NE      OAK   20 NE  30           10   TRUE 
    1 NFL_20050911_ARI@NYG      ARI   19 NYG 42           23   TRUE 
    1 NFL_20050911_CHI@WAS      CHI    7 WAS 9            2    TRUE 
    1 NFL_20050911_CIN@CLE      CIN   27 CLE 13          -14   FALSE 
    1  NFL_20050911_DAL@SD      DAL   28 SD  24           -4   FALSE 
    1 NFL_20050911_DEN@MIA      DEN   10 MIA 34           24   TRUE
```

NFL data. I want to come up with a way to pair each HTm with its Differential, and store these values in another table. I know it's easy to do, but all the methods I am coming up with involve doing each team individually via a for loop that searches for [i,5]=="NE", [i,5]=="NYG". I'm wondering if there's a way to systematically do this for all 32 teams. I would then use the same method to pair VTM of the same team code ("NYG" or "NE") with VPTs and a VDifferential.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if i understood your question correctly(you need a function like select in a database?) but:

```
cbind(matr[,x], matr[,y])
```

selects column x and y and creates a new matrix

Comment: And with slightly more effort :-) you can drag the column names along as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure why cbind didn't come to mind. 

I'm looking to create separate matrices for all 32 teams so I can conduct independent analyses of the scores. It's not too tough to do them individually, but I'm wondering if there's some sort of loop I'm not thinking of that I could run to do all 32 in one fell swoop.  Something to sort all the games into groups based on who's the home team, if that makes sense.

Comment: Addition: If have multiple rows with the same value for HTm and you want to filter them, you can use **subset(data, condition)** after this you could use sum/mean for further processing

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd like to perform operations on your data frame based on a grouping variable. For that, there are many functions, among which is `tapply()`. For example, if your data is in a data.frame object named `nflDF`, you could get the maximum `Differential` for each home team `HTm` by

```
tapply(nflDF$Differential, nflDF$HTm, FUN = max)
```

Which would return (with your sample data)

```
CLE MIA  NE NYG  SD WAS 
-14  24  10  23  -4   2
```

Alternatively, you could use `by`:

```
by(nflDF, nflDF$HTm, FUN = function(x) max(x$Differential))

HTm: CLE
[1] -14
------------------------------------------------------------ 
HTm: MIA
[1] 24
------------------------------------------------------------ 
HTm: NE
[1] 10
------------------------------------------------------------ 
HTm: NYG
[1] 23
------------------------------------------------------------ 
HTm: SD
[1] -4
------------------------------------------------------------ 
HTm: WAS
[1] 2
```

To perform more complicated operations, change the values supplied to the `FUN` arguments in the appropriate function.